# Visio add-in getting the font size of shape's text

Tags: c#, office-interop, visio

I'm trying to determine the size of the font of a shape's text.
When I use Visio as a user, I can see this value in the `Shape sheet` (under `Character->size`)
However I'm not able to understand how to access it programatically, for reading.

Which `section, Row and Cell` indexes should I use? Or maybe use the Characters object of the shape?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was successful in obtaining the formula by:

```
string fontSize = shape.CellsSRC[(short) Visio.VisSectionIndices.visSectionCharacter,
      (short) Visio.VisRowIndices.visRowCharacter,
      (short) Visio.VisCellIndices.visCharacterSize].Formula;
```

Or by:

```
string fontSize = shape.CellsSRC[3,0,7].Formula;
```

Which is practically the same, only not very readable, Or by:

```
string fontSize = shape.get_Cells("Char.Size").Formula;
```