# How to change the font of text in a Visio shape in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, fonts, visio

I am creating dynamic Visio diagrams using ASP.Net MVC. I want to change the font of text of some Visio shapes. 
If anyone know how to do it, please help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23324917/visio-add-in-getting-the-font-size-of-shapes-text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found my answer :)

shape.get_Cells("Char.Size").Formula = "=12 pt.";

Comment: Another possibility is `shape.CellsU("Char.Size").FormulaU="12 pt"`